# Why does (focus) doesn' t work in this angular2 example?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QKAnoCTNdTvk84RmtTLy?p=preview) for testing

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'test-app'
   template:`
    <h1>AngularJs 2 Material Design Demo</h1>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Your name</label>
      <input #newname />

    </md-input-container>
    <p (click)="test()" (focus)="test2()">
      Hello, {{newname.value}}
    </p>
  `,
  directives: [MdInputContainer, MdInput]
})

class TestApp {
  constructor(){
    this.title = 'AngularJs 2 Material Design Demo';
  }
  test() {

    console.log('test');
  }
  test2() {
    console.log('test2');
  }
}
```

In the above example, I added `(click)` and `(focus)` to `<p>` element.

```
<p (click)="test()" (focus)="test2()">
```

However we can see that only `click` event is propagated, while `focus` event is not propagated. Am I using focus the wrong way?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In Edit i have removed `@View`  because there in no more use of @view in beta angular2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A `p`(paragraph) or `div` tag can't receive focus. Focus can only be applies to things you can interact with, like links(anchor), input elements, textareas, button, etc

Add `tabindex` attribute  over `p` tag to receive focus event over this element, add `tabindex="0"` over `p` tag to make it working. By keeping `tabindex` to `0`, it will make sure that will perform focus, how the order of element on DOM.

**Markup**

```
<h1>AngularJs 2 Material Design Demo</h1>
<md-input-container>
  <label>Your name</label>
  <input #newname tabindex="0"/>

</md-input-container>
<p (click)="test()" (focus)="test2()" tabindex="0">
  Hello, {{newname.value}}
</p>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pTic1UQ7yyg5TBtbelkC?p=preview)

> Don't use `@View` annotation, it has already been deprecated.